# Python 2.7- Replace a string "}," with another "}" followed by a newline

Tags: python-2.7, for-loop

I have a text file with contents such that there are no line breaks. Its a file of records and I need to replace the string "}," 
I need to remove the comma without touching the other commas in the file and replace the comma which follows the closed curly brace with a new line while leaving the curly brace as is. The code below does not work

```
textToSearch = "},"
for line in fileinput.input( fileToSearch ):
    if textToSearch in line :

    tempFile.write( line.replace( textToSearch, "}\n" ) )
tempFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I got your question.

You want to find only '},' a exact match right? and replace to '\n'

I think this will gonna work for you:

```
textToSearch = "},"
for line in fileinput.input( fileToSearch ):
    if textToSearch in line:
        with open("tempFile.txt", "a") as f:
            f.write(line.replace(textToSearch, "}\n")
            f.close()
```

I have tested and its fine for me. 
Let me know if you have any other concern